# Fastapi and Pydantic to build POST API: TypeError: Object of type is not JSON serializable

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I have a problem with FastAPI and Pydantic.

I want to build a post api, program show this:

```py
@router.post('/productRoute', response_model=SuccessCreate, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_product_route(create: CreatePR):
    query = ProductRouteModel.insert().values(
        user_id=create.user_id,
        route_id=create.route_id,
        route_name=create.route_name,
        head=create.head.dict(),
        body=create.body,
        route=create.route
    )
    await database.execute(query)
    return {"status": "Successfully Created!"}
```

This is Pydantic class:

```py
class RouteSchema(BaseModel):
    id: str
    next: Optional[List[str]]
    prev: List[str]


class HeadSchema(BaseModel):
    b1: str
    b2: str
    b3: str


class BodySchema(BaseModel):
    a1: Optional[str]
    a2: Optional[str]


class CreatePR(BaseModel):
    user_id: str
    route_id: str
    route_name: str
    head: HeadSchema
    body: List[BodySchema]
    route: List[RouteSchema]
```

Finally, this i want to post's parameter format:

```json
{
    user_id: "test1",
    route_id: "route_1",
    route_name: "route_name",
    head: {...},
    body: [{...}, {...}, ..., {...}],
    route: [{...}, {...}, ..., {...}]
}
```

When I executed, I got TypeError: Object of type BodySchema is not JSON serializable.

How can I fix the program to normal operation?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK. I would not make a strong statement, but I suppose your post body is erroneous. Could you please verify whether your `JSON` format is correct or not. You could check it by using an online JSON editor (ex: https://jsonbeautifier.org/). Probable errors could be the usage of single quotes, missing/extra commas or even perhaps you forgot to put any quotes on your keys.